# How to improve homemade SQL syntax from filter function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm doing an API and the following code is used to retrieve users depending on filter. ( POST /users/search )

At the end of the function, I'm working with "LIMIT" and "OFFSET" in SQL because I want that nobody can retrieve more than 10 entries.

The code to generate the SQL query from WHERE is terrible. I am looking to improve it but I can't find a more effective way. Do you have any ideas?

```
 function getSqlFilter(filter) {
  var filterSql = '';
  if (!util.isEmpty(filter)) {
    var isFiltered = false;
    if (filter.userId != null) {
      if (!isFiltered) filterSql += ' WHERE ';
      if (isFiltered) filterSql += ' AND ';
      filterSql += 'pk_user in (' + filter.userId.toString() + ')';
      isFiltered = true;
    }
    if (filter.username != null) {
      if (!isFiltered) filterSql += ' WHERE ';
      if (isFiltered) filterSql += ' AND ';
      filterSql += 'username in (' + filter.username.toString() + ')';
      isFiltered = true;
    }
    if (filter.email != null) {
      if (!isFiltered) filterSql += ' WHERE ';
      if (isFiltered) filterSql += ' AND ';
      filterSql += 'email in (' + filter.email.toString() + ')';
      isFiltered = true;
    }
    if (filter.society != null) {
      if (!isFiltered) filterSql += ' WHERE ';
      if (isFiltered) filterSql += ' AND ';
      filterSql += 'society in (' + filter.society.toString() + ')';
      isFiltered = true;
    }
    if (filter.firstname != null) {
      if (!isFiltered) filterSql += ' WHERE ';
      if (isFiltered) filterSql += ' AND ';
      filterSql += 'firstname in (' + filter.firstname.toString() + ')';
      isFiltered = true;
    }

    if ((filter.start != null) && (filter.end != null)) {
      filter.start -= 1;
      var limit = filter.end - filter.start;
      if (limit <= 10) {
        filterSql += 'LIMIT ' + limit + ' OFFSET ' + filter.start;
      }
    } else if (filter.start != null) {
      filterSql += 'LIMIT 10 OFFSET ' + filter.start;
    } else {
      filterSql += 'LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0';
    }
  } else {
    filterSql += 'LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0';
  }
  return filterSql;
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Maybe you shoudl post this on codereview

Comment: ^ This is the link https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm sorry, this is the first time I've ever seen it exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the redundant logic and utilize ES6 features for shorter syntax.

```
function getSqlFilter(filter = {}) {
    const searches = Object.keys(filter);
    const sLength = searches.length
    let filterSql = sLength === 0 ? "LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0" : "WHERE ";
    const map = {
        userId: "pk_user",
        username: "username",
        email: "email",
        society: "society"
    }
    const { start, end } = filter;
    const hasOnlyStart = start !== undefined && end === undefined;
    const hasStartAndEnd = start !== undefined && end !== undefined;

    if (sLength) {
        filterSql += searches.map(search => {
            if(search === "start") {
                return hasOnlyStart ? `LIMIT ${filter[search]} OFFSET 10` : "";
            }
            if(search === "end") {
                return hasStartAndEnd ? `LIMIT ${filter[search]} OFFSET ${end - start}` : "";
            }
            return `${map[search]} in (${filter[search].toString()})`;
        }).join(' AND ');
    }
    return filterSql;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally do this by starting with an always true condition

```
let filter= `...
   WHERE 1 = 1`
```

Then you can simply append the filter

```
if (filter.username != null) {
  filter += ' AND username in (' + filter.username.toString() + ')'
}
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should also think about using a lib for cancating SQL strings. Otherwise you will have to deal with all the SQL-injecting stuff by yourself. A small lib I used for that was [sql-template-strings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-template-strings)

Comment: you can avoid this by adding your clauses to a set/list and joining them with an 'and'. if (clauses.length > 0) {filter += ' WHERE ' + String.join(clauses, ' AND');}

Comment: @thopaw Oh yeah, I forget about SQL-injecting!

Answer (score 1):

It is my anwser:

```
function getSqlFilter(filter) {
  let sql = '';
  let start = parseInt(filter.start);
  let end = parseInt(filter.end);
  delete filter.start;
  delete filter.end;
  const conditions = [];
  const validKey = [...your key];
  for (const key in filter){
    if(validKey.indexOf(key) !== -1){
      if(key === 'userId') conditions.push(`pk_user in (${filter[key].toString()})`);
      else conditions.push(`${key} in (${filter[key].toString()})`);
    }
  }
  if(conditions.length){
    sql = ` WHERE ${conditions.join(' AND ')}`;
  }
  let limit = 10;
  if (start) {
    if(start < 0) start = 0;
    if (end) {
      let be_limit = start - end + 1;
      if(be_limit <= 10 && be_limit >= 0) limit = be_limit;
    }
  } else {
    start = 0;
  }
  sql += ` LIMIT ${limit} OFFSET ${start}`;
  return sql;
}
```

If you don't want to change filter, please clone it before delete props.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's good. It work's with array? As filter.userId = [54,55] ?

Comment: `[55, 50].toString()` return `55,50` and become `pk_user in (55, 50)`

Comment: you should make different process for each key if they cannot just use `${key} in (${filter[key].toString()})` to solve it